# Can we print the charts, pdfs and other grid reports in ext.js?

Tags: extjs, sencha-charts

I am new to Ext.js,going to develop application using Ext.js, As per requirement need to print charts, pdfs and other grid reports. **Can anybody tell me is it possible by ext.js?** if it possible means can let me know how to achieve? please provide me related links else give me hints?. Great appreciate thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ExtJS does not allow any feature to print anything.

You need to use other libraries like aspos or open xml to generate excel sheets, pdf files in which you can draw charts, grids.

I hope this clarifies your questions.

Comment: You can google for it and you will get lot of libraries. I cannot recommend any specific library because you need to analyse your requirements and then decide on particular library.